# How can I remove non-numeric characters in cells and concatenate result to URL?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bunch of cells with string like this:
WFM 1601

And this:
WFM 2231, WFM 2402

And this too:
Campaign 1680, 2402, 2784

I used code, below, to split the string in a single cell into multiple columns (max of 3).

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next

lRow = Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRows = Range("U19:U" & lRow)
For Each cell In MyRows

splitVals = Split(cell.Value, ",")
    totalVals = UBound(splitVals)
    Range(Cells(cell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(cell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1 + totalVals)).Value = splitVals
Next
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out a way to get rid of all NON numeric characters and leave only numbers.  Then, concatenate these numbers, which are all IDs for processes in a SharePoint site that I work with, so I want to place the URL for each number, at the end of a static string, and next to the number that was just split into separate columns.

Here is a screen shot.

[image]

I have Column U, and I want to generate Column V to Column AA.

I can extract only numbers using the function below.

```
Function GetNums(target As Range)
    Dim MyStr As String, i As Integer
    MyStr = ""
    If Len(target.Value) = 0 Then GoTo GoExit
    If target.Value = "None" Then GoTo GoNone
    For i = 1 To Len(target.Value)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(target, i, 1)) Then MyStr = MyStr & Mid(target, i, 1)
    Next i
    GoTo GoExit
GoNone:
    GetNums = "None"
    Exit Function
GoExit:
    GetNums = MyStr

End Function
```

However, this won't meet the requirement as it checks all characters in a cell, and just turns this:  WFM 2231, WFM 2402 . . .
Into this: 22312402
I really need some way to distinguish the two IDs:  2231 2402

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Regular Expressions to extract the number groups. If it turns out there are other criteria for what constitutes a valid digit sequence, that would be easier to implement by changing the regex.

Here's an example with your original Data in Column A of the active sheet.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateURL()
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Const sPat As String = "\b\d+\b" 'whole words that are all digits
    Const sBaseURL As String = "htpps://collaborate.process...&ID="
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim rSrc As Range, C As Range

'This will be on active sheet
'Suggest you specify actual worksheet
Set rSrc = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    .Global = True
End With

For Each C In rSrc
    If RE.test(C.Text) = True Then
        Set MC = RE.Execute(C.Text)
        J = -1
        For Each M In MC
            J = J + 2
            C.Offset(0, J) = M
            C.Offset(0, J + 1) = sBaseURL & M
        Next M
    End If
Next C

End Sub
```

---

And here's the results of running this macro against data in column A:

[image]

Here is a formal explanation of the Regex, with links to more detail that hopefully still work:

### \b\d+\b

```
\b\d+\b
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by an ASCII letter, digit, or underscore)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`
- [Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `+`
- [Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by an ASCII letter, digit, or underscore)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: DUDE!!  THAT IS FRIGGIN' AWESOME!!!!  How does the regex part work?  For instance, where did you come up with this?  "\b\d+\b"
Is there some website you used to look that up?  I understand the rest of it, but not that part.  Thanks for everything!!!!!!

Comment: @ryguy72 I'll add a explanation of the regex to my answer.  For further details, you can examine [How to use regular expression in Microsoft Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) in this forum, and also search the MSDN knowledge base.

Comment: Thanks makes a lot more sense now.  I'm going to bookmark that site for sure.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

I can help for the 1st part, to check if a value is numeric or not.

You did the split. Now, you can check if the variables you get are numeric or not. Example :

We want to check if the value in A1 is numeric :

```
isnum = isNumeric(range("A1"))
```

isnum is true if the value in A1 is numeric, else it is false.